# How can I restrict Maintainer Role in Gitlab to deploy only to Prod

Tags: version-control, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

By default Maintainer Role in Gitlab able to deploy to all environments created ( example Prod, Stage and Dev).

Is there a way to restrict Maintainer to deploy only to Prod. environment

Answer (score 1):

As Maintainer is the highest project-level role, that's not possible to restrict it to deploy in prod. You need to solve the problem thinking the opposite : restrict the developers role to deploy in prod.

As you are using environments, it's possible using [Protected Environments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/protected_environments.html) feature (available for Premium/Silver subscription) :

1. Navigate to your project’s Settings > CI/CD
2. Expand the Protected Environments section
3. In your case, select `Prod` as environment and `Maintainer`

[image]

Then, restrict the number of users having Maintainer role.

Comment: Dead thread here, but whats stopping the Developer role from hopping into gitlab-ci.yml, changing the Production job to have an environment of "Testing", then deploying to 'my-unprotected-branch'? The CI/CD file is still targeting Production resources, regardless of whatever Environment key the dev pushed up