# How does the GitLab CICD function make a specified project member perform manual execution

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

Our developer has the authority to Maintainer, but I do not want him to be able to manually execute an pipeline in a production environment. Is there any way that a designated person can manually execute the pipeline?Or simply let root run the production environment's pipeline. :)

Comment: Hope this can answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917330/how-can-i-restrict-maintainer-role-in-gitlab-to-deploy-only-to-prod?r=SearchResults

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use the CE version, but it seems that I cannot use the above mentioned functions